# Why are complexes of type MA3B3 not optical active?

Tags: coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, optical-properties

Complexes of type $\ce{MA3B3}$ have two geometrical isomers, namely:

1. *fac*-isomer
2. *mer*-isomer

If we look closely at the *mer*-isomer, it has a plane of symmetry, so it is optically inactive.
But the *fac*-isomer has no plane of symmetry. Still, it is optically inactive, why?

Being a 12th grader, I wonder where am I wrong in my understanding of optical isomerism in coordination complexes.

Comment: Because of three planes of symmetry, to begin with.

Comment: There is no plane of symmetry in fac-isomer of type ${MA_3B_3}$

Comment: Your assertiveness is not quite justified.

Comment: there is a plane of symmetry in the fac- along the axis AMB and between two A and two B atoms. see the image here https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introchem/chapter/isomers-in-coordination-compounds/#:~:text=In%20a%20fac%20isomer%2C%20any,cis%20pairs%20of%20identical%20ligands.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I understood the point . I missed the Plane of symmetries along AMB and 2 As and Bs. That response was quite irresponsible.

Comment: Build a model of your two isomers. There are planes of symmetry in both, but they can be hard to see if you don't have a 3D model.

Comment: https://www.chemtube3d.com/symfecl3br3fac/

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti That helped a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orient the fac- isomer so one A atom is facing towards you and a space between two B atoms is below it.  Then the left half of this view is a reflection of the right half so you are actually looking down a mirror plane.

Because you could have chosen any of three A atoms in your view there are three mirror planes, which pass through a common rotation axis.  The axis passes through the face that has all A atoms at its corners and the opposite face which has all B atoms.  This symmetry is called $C_{\mathrm{3v}}$ in the language of point groups.